# Microsoft Graph API's "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again"

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-mail

> Hello everyone i'm new on Microsoft Azure platform.
> We are using mircosoft outlook graph api for send mails.
> The credentials and things are working fine. But when we are using api with /sendMail method it returns.

**Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.**

````
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET,
    authority=authority)

scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
result = None
result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes, account=None)

if not result:
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)

if "access_token" in result:
    print("Access token created.",result["access_token"])

if "access_token" in result:
    endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/sendMail'
    toUserEmail = user_email    
    email_msg = {'Message': {'Subject': "Test Sending Email from Python",
                            'Body': {'ContentType': 'Text', 'Content': "This is a test email."},
                            'ToRecipients': [{'EmailAddress': {'Address': toUserEmail}}]
                            },
                'SaveToSentItems': 'true'}
    
    r = requests.post(endpoint,headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},json=email_msg)
    if r.ok:
        print('Sent email successfully')
    else:
        print(r.json())```
````

Comment: Check if you have Mail.Send permission in your token. You can do it by putting your token in https://jwt.ms

Answer (score 2):

> I agree with *@ShivaKeshavVerma*, you need to add `Mail.Send` API permission of **Application** type to resolve your issue.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added `API permissions` like below:

[image]

When I ran the same code as you, I got access token with **same error** in response like below:

```py
import requests;
import msal;

authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>"
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id="appID",
    client_credential="secret",
    authority=authority)

scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
result = None
result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes, account=None)

if not result:
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)

if "access_token" in result:
    print("Access token created.",result["access_token"])

if "access_token" in result:
    endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>/sendMail'
    toUserEmail = "xxxxxxxxxxx@microsoft.com"  
    email_msg = {'Message': {'Subject': "Test Sending Email from Python",
                            'Body': {'ContentType': 'Text', 'Content': "This is a test email."},
                            'ToRecipients': [{'EmailAddress': {'Address': toUserEmail}}]
                            },
                'SaveToSentItems': 'true'}
    
    r = requests.post(endpoint,headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},json=email_msg)
    if r.ok:
        print('Sent email successfully')
    else:
        print(r.json())
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/), it does n't have **`roles`** claim like below:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, add `Mail.Send` **Application** permission like below:

[image]

Make sure to grant **admin consent** to above added permission like this:

[image]

When I ran the same code again, I got access token with **Sent email successfully** message in response like below:

```py
import requests;
import msal;

authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>"
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id="appID",
    client_credential="secret",
    authority=authority)

scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
result = None
result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes, account=None)

if not result:
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)

if "access_token" in result:
    print("Access token created.",result["access_token"])

if "access_token" in result:
    endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>/sendMail'
    toUserEmail = "xxxxxxxxxxx@microsoft.com"  
    email_msg = {'Message': {'Subject': "Test Sending Email from Python",
                            'Body': {'ContentType': 'Text', 'Content': "This is a test email."},
                            'ToRecipients': [{'EmailAddress': {'Address': toUserEmail}}]
                            },
                'SaveToSentItems': 'true'}
    
    r = requests.post(endpoint,headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},json=email_msg)
    if r.ok:
        print('Sent email successfully')
    else:
        print(r.json())
```

**Response:**

[image]

I decoded the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) that has **`roles`** claim with **Mail.Send** permission like below:

[image]

When I checked `Sent Items`, mail sent successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: @Scridevi Do you know how to delegate permissions from user to the application? Because you use Send.Mail permission of type Application. But this is not enabled for our organization. So I have to pass on my permissions as a user to the app. Because I of course am allowed to use my own Outlook account.