# Python send email using Graph API and Office365-REST-Python-Client

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to send an email using Graph API and Python. I tried doing it with graph explorer and it worked. I found this example: https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client#working-with-outlook-api

```
from office365.graph_client import GraphClient

client = GraphClient(acquire_token_func)

client.me.send_mail(
    subject="Meet for lunch?",
    body="The new cafeteria is open.",
    to_recipients=["fannyd@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"]
).execute_query()
```

Here's my code:

```
import msal

dict_ = {'client_id': 'foo', 'secret': 'bar', 'tenant_id': 'etc'}

def acquire_token():
    authority_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{dict_["tenant_id"]}'
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        authority=authority_url,
        client_id=dict_["client_id"],
        client_credential=dict_["secret"]
    )
    token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])
    return token


from office365.graph_client import GraphClient

client = GraphClient(acquire_token)

client.me.send_mail(
    subject="Meet for lunch?",
    body="The new cafeteria is open.",
    to_recipients=['elon.musk@company.com']
).execute_query()
```

Even though it's exactly like in the example I still get:

```
TypeError: send_mail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'subject'
```

Can you help me fix this or provide a different way of sending an email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I agree with *@user2250152*, you need to change `/me` endpoint to `client.users[<mail>].send_mail` as you are using **client credentials** flow to get token.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **`Mail.Send`** permission of **Application** type:

[image]

In my case, I used below **modified code** to send an email using Graph API and Python:

```py
import msal
import requests;

dict_ = {'client_id': 'appId', 'secret': 'secret', 'tenant_id': 'tenantId'}

def acquire_token():
    authority_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{dict_["tenant_id"]}'
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        authority=authority_url,
        client_id=dict_["client_id"],
        client_credential=dict_["secret"]
    )
    token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])
    return token

result = acquire_token()

if "access_token" in result:
    print("Access token created.",result["access_token"])

if "access_token" in result:
    endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userId/sendMail'
    toUserEmail = "sri@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"  
    email_msg = {'Message': {'Subject': "Meet for lunch?",
                            'Body': {'ContentType': 'Text', 'Content': "The new cafeteria is open."},
                            'ToRecipients': [{'EmailAddress': {'Address': toUserEmail}}]
                            },
                'SaveToSentItems': 'true'}
    
    r = requests.post(endpoint,headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},json=email_msg)
    if r.ok:
        print('Sent email successfully')
    else:
        print(r.json())
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the **`Sent Items`** where email sent successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[python - Microsoft Graph API's "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again" - Stack Overflow by **me**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75650693/microsoft-graph-apis-access-is-denied-check-credentials-and-try-again/75658620#75658620)

Comment: Thanks, your solution using REST API works. I wanted to use a library because I am not sure how to send emails other than text ones ie what if I want to send an image, an attachment? I am under an impression that using a library will make it easier. Anyway, at least the basic stuff works for now.

Answer (score 0):

You are using client id and secret, in that case you cannot call `client.me.send_mail`.

**me** can be called only when you are logged as a user.

Try to use

```
client.users[<mail>].send_mail(
    subject="Meet for lunch?",
    body="The new cafeteria is open.",
    to_recipients=['elon.musk@company.com']
).execute_query()
```

Comment: thanks, now I know but I still get the same error(