# Send mail from Outlook with Python and Graph API - Authentication Problem

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I have written a Python script that uses the [office365](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client) library and loads Excel files from SharePoint to my local system. From there I push selected content via SQL Alchemy to a SQL server.

This process is to run daily as a routine gathering data for a report. The problem with Excel however is that people work with it. Therefore I expect things to go wrong sometimes. For example, a file not being available or just having a name that is slightly off (and not caught by my regex).

Luckily the report users are also the file providers. Therefore I would like to implement checks in my script that automatically send problems to the file providers (and to me) if the script can't do its job.

To begin with, I want to send a mail from my outlook account. To do so I want to use the Microsoft Graph API.

I have found my tenant ID and went to entra.microsoft.com to create an application. I gave the application the Mail.Send and Mail.Send.Shared permission and I created a client secret.

With that, I was able to write the following code.

```
import msal
import requests
import json

TENANT_ID = 'Tenant ID'
AUTHORITY_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + TENANT_ID
CLIENT_ID = 'Client ID'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'Client Secret'
SCOPES = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET,
    authority=AUTHORITY_URL)

result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=SCOPES)

userId = "My Outlook Mail Adress"
endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/sendMail'
toUserEmail = "My Outlook Mail Adress"
email_msg = {'Message': {'Subject': "Test Sending Email from Python",
                         'Body': {'ContentType': 'Text', 'Content': "This is a test email."},
                         'ToRecipients': [{'EmailAddress': {'Address': toUserEmail}}]
                         },
             'SaveToSentItems': 'true'}
r = requests.post(endpoint,
                  headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},
                  json=email_msg)
if r.ok:
    print('Sent email successfully')
else:
    print(r.json())
```

However, the Graph API replies with:

> {'error': {'code': 'ErrorAccessDenied', 'message': 'Access is denied.
> Check credentials and try again.'}}

So I guess, I do something wrong when delegating my users permissions to the application. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/permissions-consent-overview?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps) is the Microsoft documentation I found about this topic.

Do you know how I have to change my code in order to get permission to send the mail?

As far as I can see, I am doing things exactly as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76805337/python-send-email-using-graph-api-and-office365-rest-python-client) question's answer. But what worked for them, doesn't do the trick for me.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75650693/microsoft-graph-apis-access-is-denied-check-credentials-and-try-again/75658620#75658620) question is also closely related. The only difference that I can spot is that the person who answered gave the application the Mail.Send permission on an application level and I would like to work with the Delegated Level because the other is not enabled by our organization.

[image]

Edit as reply to the answer from Jesse:
When I run your code I need to ask for approval. Is this avoidable?

[image]

Comment: Hm... So *technically* I'm sure you could automate that, but you'd have to use selenium or something (essentially fake going to the site and entering in the code). HOWEVER, you only need to authenticate yourself ONCE, then it will use a refresh token instead of bugging you.

Your real problem is your org doesn't currently allow you to use this to automatically send emails, so you'll need that administrator to grant you access (then you'll only need to authenticate yourself by going to the site and entering the code one time)

Comment: Oh, and in case you were asking if there is away around needing admin approval---no, that's a pretty set-in-stone security measure.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently been putting a lot of work into interacting with my drive and email using the Graph API and initially got stuck exactly where you are.

It looks like you've given your APP everything it needs to interact with your org but not what it needs to access/interact with your actual account.

From their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msal/msal.application.confidentialclientapplication?view=msal-py-latest) for `Confidential Client App`

> acquire_token_for_client:
> Acquires token for the current confidential
> client, not for an end user.

You'd want

> acquire_token_on_behalf_of: Acquires token using on-behalf-of (OBO)
> flow.
>
> The current app is a middle-tier service which was called with a token
> representing an end user. The current app can use such token (a.k.a. a
> user assertion) to request another token to access downstream web API,
> on behalf of that user.

Sorry, needed a minute to get something working for you.

There are a few ways to get/managed your user tokens.

My recommendation:
create a config file `config.cfg`

```
[azure]
client_id = your_client_id (app)
username = your_user_name
tenant_id = your_org_tenant_id
```

(obviously dotenv works just as well, but taking this from a project where I'm handling a bunch of stuff)

```
import requests
import msal
from msal_extensions import *
import sys
import configparser
import jwt
import json
import datetime

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.cfg')
settings = config['azure']


# mine
authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{settings["tenant_id"]}'
scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']


class GraphAPI:
    """
    A simple way to interact with the MSAL authentication system using new
    and cached credentials (so we don't have to go through the authorization
    flow every time
    """

    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username
        self.token = self.get_access_token(username)
        self.tokenExp = self.msal_jwt_expiry(self.token)
        self.uri = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0'
        self.headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.token}',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    def msal_persistence(self, location, fallback_to_plaintext=False):
        """Build a suitable persistence instance based your current OS"""
        if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
            return FilePersistenceWithDataProtection(location)
        if sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
            return KeychainPersistence(location, "my_service_name", "my_account_name")
        return FilePersistence(location)

    def msal_cache_accounts(self, client_id, authority):
        # Accounts
        persistence = self.msal_persistence("token_cache.bin")
        cache = PersistedTokenCache(persistence)
        app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
            client_id=client_id, authority=authority, token_cache=cache)
        accounts = app.get_accounts()
        return accounts

    def msal_delegated_refresh(self, client_id, scope, authority, account):
        persistence = self.msal_persistence("token_cache.bin")
        cache = PersistedTokenCache(persistence)
        app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
            client_id=client_id, authority=authority, token_cache=cache)
        result = app.acquire_token_silent_with_error(
            scopes=scope, account=account)
        return result

    def msal_delegated_refresh_force(self, client_id, scope, authority, account):
        persistence = self.msal_persistence("token_cache.bin")
        cache = PersistedTokenCache(persistence)
        app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
            client_id=client_id, authority=authority, token_cache=cache)
        result = app.acquire_token_silent_with_error(
            scopes=scope, account=account, force_refresh=True)
        return result

    def msal_delegated_device_flow(self, client_id, scope, authority):
        persistence = self.msal_persistence("token_cache.bin")
        cache = PersistedTokenCache(persistence)
        app = msal.PublicClientApplication(client_id=client_id, authority=authority, token_cache=cache)
        flow = app.initiate_device_flow(scopes=scope)
        if "user_code" not in flow:
            raise ValueError("Fail to create device flow. Err: %s" % json.dumps(flow, indent=4))
        else:
            print(flow['message'])
            print(f'verification_url: {flow["verification_uri"]}')
            print(f'user_code: {flow["user_code"]}')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        result = app.acquire_token_by_device_flow(flow)
        return result

    def msal_jwt_expiry(self, access_token):
        alg = jwt.get_unverified_header(access_token)['alg']
        decoded_access_token = jwt.decode(access_token, algorithms=[alg], options={"verify_signature": False})
        # token expiry
        token_expiry = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(decoded_access_token["exp"])
        return token_expiry

    def get_access_token(self, username):
        accounts = self.msal_cache_accounts(client_id=settings['client_id'],
                                            authority=authority)
        if accounts:
            for account in accounts:
                if account['username'].lower() == username.lower():
                    my_account = account
                    result = self.msal_delegated_refresh(settings['client_id'], scope, authority, my_account)
                    if result is None:
                        # Get a new Access Token using the Device Code Flow
                        result = self.msal_delegated_device_flow(settings['client_id'], scope, authority)
                    else:
                        if result["access_token"]:
                            self.msal_jwt_expiry(result["access_token"])
        else:
            print('there are no accounts, using msal_delegated_device_flow')
            # get new access token using the device flow code
            result = self.msal_delegated_device_flow(settings['client_id'], scope, authority)
            if result["access_token"]:
                # token expiry
                self.msal_jwt_expiry(result["access_token"])
        return result['access_token']

    def get(self, endpoint):
        results = requests.get(url=f'{self.uri}{endpoint}',
                               headers=self.headers).json()
        return results

    def post(self, endpoint, data):
        results = requests.post(url=f'{self.uri}{endpoint}',
                                data=json.dumps(data),
                                headers=self.headers)
        return results

    def patch(self, endpoint, data):
        results = requests.patch(url=f'{self.uri}{endpoint}',
                                 data=data,
                                 headers=self.headers).json()
        return results


graph = GraphAPI(settings['username'])
```

EDIT: Sorry, had initially used `device_code` instead of `user_code`, which is completely useless for you.

Then, if you want something simple for sending emails

```
def send_email(recipients: list[str],
               subject: str,
               content: str,
               is_html: bool,
               cc_recipients: list[str] = [],
               bcc_recipients: list[str] = [],
               save_to_sent: bool = True):
    data = {'message': {'subject': subject,
                        'body': {'contentType': 'HTML' if is_html else 'text',
                                 'content': content},
                        'toRecipients': [],
                        "ccRecipients": [],
                        "bccRecipients": []
                        },
            "saveToSentItems": "true" if save_to_sent else "false"
            }
    for r in recipients:
        data['message']['toRecipients'].append({'emailAddress': {'address': r}})
    for r in bcc_recipients:
        data['message']['bccRecipients'].append({'emailAddress': {'address': r}})
    for r in cc_recipients:
        data['message']['ccRecipients'].append({'emailAddress': {'address': r}})
    return graph.post(endpoint='/me/sendmail', data=data)


send_email(['YOUR_EMAIL'], 'test email', 'i am a test email', False)
```

Comment: thank you a lot for your answer. I currently test whether I get the code going.

Comment: @MerlinNestler By the way, I think it matters you use `PyJWT` not just the `jwt` package.

Comment: when I run your code, I am told to go to https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter a code. When I do that I get forwarded to a page where I have to request approval. I add a screenshot to my question so you know what I mean. Can I somehow do that in a programmatic way? I would like to run this without manual input being necessary.

Comment: @MerlinNestler Sorry, my org has a bunch of 2FA stuff, so I never really messed with that. BUT, you only have to do this ONCE---then it will use the refresh token (and you don't have to enter your info again)---does having to manually authenticate once per user mess you up?

Comment: no, that should actually be fine. I will just have to contact the admins to give the permission. Thank you for your comment. I will try again.